# Vue 3 filtering array does not create new array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to understand when you filter a reactive array in vue 3 to create a new array and then change a property on the new array why its updating the original array. Shouldn't filter create a brand new array without any knowledge of the original array? Help me understand.
Here is a codesandbox of what I'm talking about.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-glziy?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Thanks

Comment: That link doesn't go to your example.

Comment: If you’re using an array of objects, the filtered array still contains objects that point/refer to the same objects in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok never mind I figured it out. Filter creates a shallow copy. I did not know that. So it will keep a reference to the original object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy